# What's the difference between $(ap)(x)$ and $ap(x)$ if $p$ is a polynomial and $a$ is constant?

Tags: polynomials

Would it be correct to say $(ap)(x)$ is a polynomial $ap$ evaluated at $x$ and $ap(x)$ is a polynomial $p$ evaluated at $x$ with all its coefficients multiplied by $a$?

Comment: Say you have a function $f$. What is the difference between $(af)(x)$ and $a(f(x))$? Hint: $f(x)$ is a value.

Comment: $af$ is a function evaluated at $x$ and $a(f(x))$ is a function $a$ evaluated at $f(x)$?

Comment: No; $a p(x)$ would be the value you get by evaluating $p$ at $x$ and then multiplying the result by $a$. The polynomial $a p$ is the polynomial you get by multiplying all the coefficients of $p$ by $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these functions are both maps $\mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$, the expressions are identical. $ap$ is the function that maps $x\mapsto a\cdot (p(x))$ for each $x$ in the domain of $p$.